# RAM types and speed

Tags: memory

What are the main criteria for selecting "good" RAM? Obviously, everyone wants *quantity* with RAM, 16GB is better than 8GB, but what about *quality*? What are the main factors involved? When I see two RAM sticks, each with the same quantity of RAM, at two different price points, how should I determine what to get?

Is there such a thing as RAM speed, and does it make a significant difference which makes a disparity in price justifiable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Priority one: Clock speed. Higher numbers are better.

Priority two: Latency. Lower numbers are better.

Priority three: Voltage. Lower numbers are better.

Priority four: Heat sink. Cooler looking is better.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you elaborate a bit esp. on points one and two? I understand three and four: less heat and less power are usually always a better option. So RAM has a clock speed; is this variable, like on a CPU? Does RAM always run at the clock specified?

Comment: Modern RAM has a maximum clock speed. It will happily run at a lower clock speed. One of the reasons clock speed is important is that when you run RAM at a lower clock speed, generally the latency (measured in clock cycles) decreases.

Comment: Most importantly, make sure the RAM is of the right type. If it will not fit with your motherboard, or if you want ECC etc

Comment: One of the priority is **brand**. Don't ever go for cheap brands, you will be disappointed.

Comment: Basically, any brand you've heard of is fine. But if no brand is mentioned or it's a brand you've never heard of, watch out -- you may get whatever junk is lying around.

Comment: @TKKocheran For points one and two see: [How does RAM frequency and latency differ? How does it affect performance?](http://superuser.com/questions/238083/how-does-ram-frequency-and-latency-differ-how-does-it-affect-performance), and also check out [Memory timings and RAM?](http://superuser.com/questions/12395/memory-timings-and-ram)

Comment: @SachinDivekar "Value RAM" by quality brands is the best choice (IMO); unless you want to over-clock and/or enjoy screwing around with finicky "enthusiast" RAM, you're just burning money on shiny/blinky bells and whistles you'll never see. ;)